# Xmlhttprequest with a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an array of URL's, example: `["http://google.com", "http://anothersite.com"]`

Here's my code:

```
var arr = getarray // This is the array above

$.get( arr, function(getcode){
console.log(getcode)
});
```

I need the XMLhttprequest to get all of the information from the links in the array.

Is this possible?

Comment: this is not only javascript. Please use correct tagging when you're using frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by getting the deferred object from each request and handling them when all have completed using `$.when`:

```
var arr = getarray
var promises = arr.map(function(url) {
   return $.get(url);
});

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
   // do something with arguments
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
   args.forEach(function(responseData, index) {
     // data
   });
});
```